# Contingency tables vs Kolmogorov Smirnov

Tags: kolmogorov-smirnov-test, contingency-tables, fishers-exact-test

I ran an experiment with a treatment group and a control group. All subjects were asked to choose an integer between 1 and 80 (which was the variable of interest), to indicate the amount of money they were willing to pay for an object. There were a total of 180 subjects, so some integers were not chosen.

I want to see whether the distributions were different in the treatment group compared to the control group. Which test is better?

1) The Kolmogorov-Smirnov test (which is strictly speaking for continuous data)

2) Contingency tables with Fisher's exact test?

Answer (score 1):

Given the context of your data, I recommend the KS test, or a Wilcoxon Rank Sum (aka Mann-Whitney U) test. Please see assumptions: https://statistics.laerd.com/spss-tutorials/wilcoxon-signed-rank-test-using-spss-statistics.php

The use of a Fisher's exact test makes sense if you have two categorical variables producing something something like a 2 x 3 contingency table. From your question, it seems you may potentially have a 2 x 80 contingency table if you treat each monetary value as a level in the `Money` category by the `Group` factor. Hence, it doesn't make sense to use a Fisher's exact test for your analysis.

To briefly explain each test:

Kolmogorov-Smirnov

> An attractive feature of this test is that the distribution of the K-S test statistic itself does not depend on the underlying cumulative
> distribution function being tested. Another advantage is that it is an
> exact test (the chi-square goodness-of-fit test depends on an adequate
> sample size for the approximations to be valid). Despite these
> advantages, the K-S test has several important limitations:
>
> 1. It only applies to continuous distributions.
> 2. It tends to be more sensitive near the center of the distribution than at the tails.
> 3. Perhaps the most serious limitation is that the distribution must be fully
>    specified. That is, if location, scale, and shape parameters are
>    estimated from the data, the critical region of the K-S test is no
>    longer valid. It typically must be determined by simulation.

http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/eda/section3/eda35g.htm

Contingency tables with Fisher's exact test

> "is used when you want to conduct a chi-square test but one or more of
> your cells has an expected frequency of five or less.  Remember that
> the chi-square test assumes that each cell has an expected frequency
> of five or more, but the Fisher's exact test has no such assumption
> and can be used regardless of how small the expected frequency is."

(http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/spss/whatstat/whatstat.htm)